SQL timeout from a simple, one table, query
My query is dead simple but sometimes it gets a timeout exception.
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM [cmn].[ProductChange] 
WHERE shop_id = @shopId 
ORDER BY changed_at DESC

This is the execution plan:

If I test the query in SSMS, the first time it is really slow, over 30 seconds, but the next times, it's much faster.
This is the primary key of the table:
ALTER TABLE [cmn].[ProductChange] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_cmn_ProductChange] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([product_id] ASC)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

I have about 350k rows which I don't think that are that much. Are they?
I have only one FK with the Shop, the PK is an external ID and it's not connected to any other table.
My columns are:
product_Id PK, BigInt
shop_id FK, BigInt
column1 nvarchar(800)
column2 nvarchar(max)
column_3 smallint
changed_at datetime2(7)
column_4 datetime2(7)
column_5 datetime2(7)

How can I make this query much faster?

The fact you have a key lookup means you don't have a suitable index. Do you really need every column? What columns is the index IX_ProductChange_s... ordered on and what columns does it INCLUDE? Does that contain all the columns you actually need?

If the index is sufficient to both filter for shop_id and directly identify the top 100 changed_at values, the 100 key lookup actions should not be a performance concern. I recommend that you check for an index on ProductChange(shop_id, changed_at) and add one if not present.

If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

What is the maximum number of rows that any one shop_id contains? At the moment it isn't even clear that the timeouts are due to it needing to do a large number of lookups (and sort) or some other reason such as blocking

The improved speed for the second run is most likely due to data already residing in memory from the prior run. You can eliminate this variable by running the command DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to clear out this data before each performance test. Note that this affects the entire server, not just the current session or database, so use cautiously outside of a development or test environment.

select * is a code smell - I think that has already been pointed out - but to reiterate, it can have a severely detrimental impact on performance. In fact, a TOP (100) query is somewhat confusing here - what is the purpose of this query? Is this a real life production issue or are you using this query for testing purposes only? I think of course like everyone else that indexes may help, or the problem may have to do with other things such as waits or memory spikes ...) Nevertheless, it is very hard to suggest any useful SQL Server index for a star select ... what columns to include?

Here is a fiddle with scaled down data having 10 shops with 1000 rows each, and a query selecting the top 10 rows for one shop. The query is executed using several index options and shows the execution plans. Note that the ProductChange(shop_id, changed_at) index significantly reduces the number of key lookups needed and the ProductChange(shop_id, changed_at) include(other_information) eliminates the key lookup entirely. However, index space statistics at the end shows that a fully covering include has increased cost for wide (lots of data per row) tables.

@ThomA The index you mentions includes only the shop_id (ASC). I haven't inlcude any columns to the index.

@TN Thank you for your effort, it seems that your suggestion to create ProductChange(shop_id, changed_at) will help allot. I do have nvarchar(max) at my table so I won't add the data in the index

The reason your query is slow is almost certainly because it has to read the all matching shop_id rows, do Key Lookups for all of them, and then sort to get those 100 rows. On subsequent runs all that data is in the cache so it's faster.
Looks like you need the following index to support your query
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_changed_at ON cmn.ProductChange
  (shop_id ASC, changed_at DESC);

Ideally you would have INCLUDE columns on that index for all your SELECT columns, but I don't know what this SELECT * involves. You should really only specify the exact columns you need, and only put those into the INCLUDE.

I added the suggested index, it seems reasonable and I hope it will help.
